# Cannot get gitHub API to work in javascript. Specifically gitdata.getCommit

Tags: javascript, github

```
var GitHubApi = require("github");

var github = new GitHubApi({
    // required
    version: "3.0.0",
    // optional
    debug: true,
    protocol: "https",
    host: "github.com",
    //pathPrefix: "/joyent/node", // for some GHEs
    timeout: 5000
});
github.gitdata.getCommit({
    user: "bnoordhuis",
    repo: "/joyent/node",
    sha: "c30cc4e3a5ead3ca5b48e8eec445740775888ed8"
}, function(err, res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
});
```

I posted the code above.  I found a random branch in github for testing.  I also found a random user as well as that user's commit randomly.  I read information about the API here: http://mikedeboer.github.io/node-github/#gitdata.prototype.getCommit

When I run the code above, I get error code 404, null bnoordhuis
undefined

Any help would be awesome!  I am a noob to using github api.

Here is the repo I am trying to use: https://github.com/joyent/node/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your repository should just be 'node'. Joyent is the user.